# Client PC authentication in ASP.NET MVC (Advice needed)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, security, client-certificates

I've have some authentication scenario that I'm not sure how to approach. I'll appreciate any advice on the subject.

Requirement:

1. Website will contain one section
   that will be **only** available to
   specific computers.
2. Website needs to be aware which PC is currently making request (I need to be able to tie this PC to other tables in Database)
3. We have full access to PCs that will be accessing website
4. Website cannot require login, user should be just presented with content pages without need for logging in.
5. Solution needs to be secure since, it will have to pass security audit
6. Assume that every PC is on different network.

My ideas so far:

- use client certificates but I'm
  not sure whether you can issue
  different certificate per client? If
  the answer is 'you don't know who is
  making the request' than it's failing
  requirement number 2 and therefore is
  not an option.
- Windows
  Authentication with impersonation so
  I can have different users logged in
  on PC (I'm in control what will be
  the user name/account logged in on
  the machine)
- Basic Authentication and set PC to remember username/password first time. I'm a bit afraid that this "remember me" can expire which would cause big chaos since someone would have to setup this PC(s) again...
- Windows Identity
  Foundation - never tried but if I can
  implement this scenario here in some
  nice way I appreciate if you can
  point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance for your help.

**EDIT:**
I would prefer not to use SSL if possible... (performance consideration)

**EDIT2:**
Currently I think that the best option would be to check whether PC is authenticated (whether it contains Forms Authentication cookie) and if it is not then redirect him to some https:// page that will check client certificate, set cookie if cert exists and redirect back to target page.
This shouldn't be slow since SSL will be used only in rare cases when cookie expires.
Please let me know if you see any flaws in this solution. 
If you know how to create server certificate and later generate different client certificates from it I would be grateful for guidelines.